# Hide price for out of stock products

Tags: php, price, html, price-rules

How to hide price for out of stock products in all Magento pages.(product pages and category pages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally price is render by below code:

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
```

And magento is check in stock by using below code:

```
$_product->isSaleable().
```

At list.phtml file add this as condition like :

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product,true); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

At view.phtml  and condition like:

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
 <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

**Also you can do this by css:**

add css code at list.phtml and view.phtml file:

```
<?php if(!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<style type="text/css">

.price-box {display:none;}
</style>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: the css code you presented is working fine on product page but it will hide price box for all products (both of in stock and out of stock products).

Answer (score 0):

just replace:

```
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
```

about at line 73 of list.phtml to:

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                         <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```