# Hide out of stock price from category Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, stock, out-of-stock

I want to hide out of stock product price from category but I want to remain the product on same category but only hide price when the product come back to store then it will show price.

Can anyone give me a suggestion?

Comment: Duplicate - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/61272/hide-price-for-out-of-stock-products

Comment: sir that is not helpful that why i ask again.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the `list.phtml` and the `view.phtml` templates of your theme.

You need use the `Template Path Hints` feature of Magento to detect these, which you can find here:

> Backend > System > Configuration > Advanced section > 
>   Developer tab > Debug fieldset

Please pay attention, that it accessible only in a **Website** and **Store View** scopes.

For the default theme of the RWD design package you can find these by the following path:

> Magento_root/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/

For the `view.phtml` template please wrap the div of the **price-info** class with if statement:

```
<?php if ($_product->getIsInStock()): ?>
    <div class="price-info">
        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bundle_prices') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

For the `list.phtml` you need make wrapping twice (for the List and the Grid modes):

1) List mode:

```
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <div class="product-secondary">
        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

2) Grid mode:

```
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```